# Can Neewer NW-700 microphone work with Behringer Xenyx 502?

Tags: voice, microphones, mixer

I am planning on buying this [microphone](https://www.amazon.de/Professional-Broadcasting-Microphone-Adjustable-Suspension/dp/B00XOXRTX6/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1474727266&sr=8-1&keywords=neewer%20nw-700) and this [audio mixer](https://www.amazon.de/Behringer-502-Xenyx-mixer/dp/B000J5UEGQ/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1474727295&sr=8-1&keywords=behringer%20xenyx%20502) and I was wondering if they can work together and if I can connect them to my laptop?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, but mostly no. This is all analogue audio equipment, so there are no "compatibility issues" per se, but you would need a few other pieces of equipment for this microphone and mixer to work together, and further equipment to work with your laptop.

This microphone appears to be a condenser type of capsule, not a dynamic type, which means it requires 48V phantom power to be supplied over the microphone cable. The Behringer mixer does not have any indication that it supplies phantom power. To compensate for this, you could purchase an [inline phantom power supply](https://www.amazon.com/Microphone-Phantom-Power-Supplies/b?ie=UTF8&node=11974571) that goes between the mixer and the microphone (and an additional XLR cable to hook that up). Many mixers exist that supply phantom power on their own, so you might want to look for an alternative.

Additionally, to hook this setup up to your laptop, ideally you will want some kind of USB audio interface. Behringer has an [offering](https://www.amazon.de/Behringer-U-Control-UCA202-Interface-Soundkarte/dp/B000KW2YEI/ref=sr_1_6?ie=UTF8&qid=1474731785&sr=8-6&keywords=behringer+USB) that you could hook up to the 2-track in/outs on the mixer, or you could use the main outs with the appropriate cables. But again, other mixers may have a USB interface built-in.

You might consider going a very different route and not buying a mixer. A recording interface like [this](https://www.amazon.de/Presonus-AudioBox-Kompaktes-USB-Recording-Interface/dp/B00154KSA2/ref=sr_1_9?ie=UTF8&qid=1474731966&sr=8-9&keywords=USB+phantom+power) will power your condenser mic and plug directly into your laptop, while likely offering much higher sound quality than the Behringer. Personally, I've got my eye on a [Mackie Blackjack](http://mackie.com/products/onyx-blackjack).

Comment: https://www.amazon.de/Pronomic-00024058-M-502-Mixer/dp/B004FF38LY/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1474737300&sr=8-1&keywords=48v%2Bmixer&th=1

What do You think about this product?

Comment: @user33527 I've never heard of Pronomic before. Does it do what you want, for the price you want to pay?

Comment: I like it pretty much and in the description it says that it has a phantom power 48v and I was wondering if I could use this device without an external phantom power?

Comment: @user33527 Yes, that's what the switch on the front that says "PHANTOM" means.

Comment: Will my laptop be able to support this device?

Comment: @user33527 Does your laptop have a recording-quality onboard line-level audio interface? I have no idea. As I said in my answer, generally you want your audio equipment to interface with your laptop via USB, which this device clearly does not have. I included an example of a standalone USB interface in my answer, and david strachan's answer recommends a mixer that has one onboard. Please try to figure out how this stuff works for yourself and ask for help when something is not making sense to you. I'm more than happy to help explain a confusing topic, but I'm not going to go shopping for you.

Answer (score 0):

If the mixer is a Q502USB it has phantom power,required by your choice of microphone, and USB reqired for laptop.